# Table of products with CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make products catalog with React and CSS. Everything seems to be okay except last row of products.

The last row has only 1 element and since the `flex-grow: 1` is set, it takes up all the available width.

Is it possible to set the same width for all elements in the row?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  }
  .products__product {
     flex: 1 0 20%;
     margin: 1.5em 0.75em 0 0.75em;
     min-height: 250px;
     background:grey;
  }
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="products__content">
      <ul>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/stone-in-the-night"
          ><li><h1>Stone in the Night</h1></li></a
        ><a class="products__product" href="/products/21/the-dying-of-the-spirits"
          ><li><h1>The Dying of the Spirits</h1></li></a
        ><a class="products__product" href="/products/21/the-beginnings-guardian"
          ><li><h1>The Beginning&amp;#8217;s Guardian</h1></li></a
        ><a class="products__product" href="/products/21/death-of-light"
          ><li><h1>Death of Light</h1></li></a
        ><a class="products__product" href="/products/21/the-lost-soul"
          ><li><h1>The Lost Soul</h1></li></a
        ><a class="products__product" href="/products/21/first-husband"
          ><li><h1>First Husband</h1></li></a
        ><a class="products__product" href="/products/21/verzliaraktis"
          ><li><h1>Veržliaraktis</h1></li></a
        ><a class="products__product" href="/products/21/raktas"
          ><li><h1>Raktas</h1></li></a
        >
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you replicate your code, include the html code output?

Comment: My code is in react.js. Added it to the post.

Comment: Added it to the post.

Comment: is it 5 columns in a row?

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the initial width to a percentage:

```
.products__product {
  ...
  flex: 0 0 20%
  ...
}
```

The above says, do not shrink nor grow the items, but set it to 20% of the width of the container. So even if you have a single element in the container, it will only occupy 20%. You can adjust based on the number of elements you have. Unfortunately, you can't use fractional notation.

Comment: But it doesn't take all the available space. Maybe there is a way to add something like a placeholder?

Comment: Or you could stick with your original, and simply add invisible elements (ie, `visibility: hidden`) which still take up space but are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the width of the `products__product` class if you want to keep them uniform.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;

  .products__product {
     width: 30%; // 3 per row
     margin: 1.5em 0.75em 0 0.75em;
     min-height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.products__product {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  min-width: 20%;
  margin: 1.5em 0.75em 0 0.75em;
  min-height: 250px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="products__content">
      <ul>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/stone-in-the-night">
          <li>
            <h1>Stone in the Night</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/the-dying-of-the-spirits">
          <li>
            <h1>The Dying of the Spirits</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/the-beginnings-guardian">
          <li>
            <h1>The Beginning&amp;#8217;s Guardian</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/death-of-light">
          <li>
            <h1>Death of Light</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/the-lost-soul">
          <li>
            <h1>The Lost Soul</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/first-husband">
          <li>
            <h1>First Husband</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/verzliaraktis">
          <li>
            <h1>Veržliaraktis</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="products__product" href="/products/21/raktas">
          <li>
            <h1>Raktas</h1>
          </li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```